# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: python

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку PyTorch, но возникает следующая ошибка:

```py
    (venv) D:\Python\PycharmProjects\TGBot>pip install torch===1.4.0 torchvision===0.5.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
    Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
    Collecting torch===1.4.0
      WARNING: Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.4.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (796.8 MB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 796.8 MB 5.1 kB/s
    ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Памяти на основном диске должно вроде хватать (на диске С свободно 1.5 ГБ, а для пакета требуется в два раза меньше).

Вообще сам проект лежит на D, где очень много места.
Но ему скорее всего не хватает в /temp/. (ОЗУ на ноуте 4 ГБ)

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А разве он не распаковывает эти 800мб после скачки и устанавливает из распакованного? То есть суммарно там сильно за 2гб выходит

Comment: написано же "No space left on device" это значит что недостаточно места на диске куда производится запись это ошибка ОС. расширьте диск C.